# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection) in jmeter JDBC request

Tags: jmeter-5.0

Getting error in Jmeter JDBC request of Select query only for 400 users load.

Error is : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)

JDBC Connection Configuration:

[image]

Comment: Show `ServerName` variable value

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<servername>:1521/<dbinstancename>

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue for "Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)".

In my JDBC connection configuration, i have used max number of connection is zero and this is the root cause of this error.

To resolve my issue, i have configure max number of connection as number of user load to be running as variable. As i'm running script from CMD so i have passing the value of user load from command line parameter and that value is used in config file.